# Animating words with jQuery

Tags: jquery, animation

I have no idea what I'm doing with jQuery. I'm trying to animate words one after the other.

For example:

A word on the left (unseen) would fade in while it slides in, and the other word would fade slide in from the right. Then both words will fade out and and a new set of words will do the same. Here's the hot mess I have so far:

```
$(function() {
    $('.fadel').animate({
        left: '250px'
    }, 3575, function() {
        $(this).fadeOut();
    });

    $('.fader').animate({
        right: '250px'
    }, 3575, function() {
        $(this).fadeIn();
        $(this).fadeOut();
    });

});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: show us also the html code please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/xPXqV/1/

```
$(function()
{
  var num = 0;
  var words =
  [
    {left: "foo", right: "bar"},
    {left: "holy", right: "crap"},
    {left: "train", right: "spotting"}
  ];    

  var fadel = $('#fadeL');
  var fader = $('#fadeR');

  animate();

  function animate()
  {
    var leftword = words[num].left;
    var rightword = words[num].right;

    fadel
        .stop()
        .css('left', '0px')
        .css('opacity', 0)
        .text(leftword).show();

    fader
        .stop()
        .css('left', '500px')
        .css('opacity', 0)
        .text(rightword).show();
    fadel.animate({
        opacity: 1,
        left: (250 - fadel.width()) + 'px'
    }, 3575, function() {
        fadel.fadeOut("slow", function()
        {
            queueNext();
        });
    });

    fader.animate({
        opacity: 1,
        left: '250px'
    }, 3575, function() {  
        fader.fadeOut("slow");
    });
}

function queueNext()
{
    if (++num == words.length)
        num = 0;

    animate();
}
```

});

Comment: How can I pause the animations after the first 2 words are shown?

Comment: By putting the calls fadel.animate and fader2.animate (16 lines) inside this block setTimeout(function(){ /* here */ }, 2000);